# Upgrading to SQL Server 2005: Cannot INSERT QNAN into float column?

Tags: c++, sql-server-2005, sqlncli

**Background:**
I'm working on migrating from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005.  This is providing DB service for a C++ application that uses SQL Native Client to communicate with SQL Server via ODBC.

**Problem:**
I'm attempting to insert QNAN into a float column in the database.  In my application, this value is stored as a double (value: 1.#QNAN00000000000) and is sent into the database as a parameter.  This was not a problem in SQL Server 2000 but the same code gives me the following error in SQL Server 20005:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS)
>   remote procedure call (RPC) protocol
>   stream is incorrect. Parameter 3 (""):
>   The supplied value is not a valid
>   instance of data type float. Check the
>   source data for invalid values. An
>   example of an invalid value is data of
>   numeric type with scale greater than
>   precision.

**Question**:
Is it possible to get SQL Server 2005 to accept QNAN?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the response to [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=239674), SQL Server 2005 does not accept NaN or infinity, and this was apparently by design (due to sorting/comparison issues).

Answer (score 2):

QNAN's are not supported under sql 2005.  Neither are NAN's

Technically speaking they weren't supported under SQL 2000 either.  However, they worked.

You might want to review the following:

DATA_PURITY Checks under SQL 2005
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923247

Another place you might want to visit is:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1119